# How to change the label colors of a custom dashboard in superset

Tags: apache-superset

I I have created a custom dashboard in superset and I want to change the label color, I am able to do this the existing dashboards that are already available but for the customs ones I am not able to do so

Here is what I have tried

```
"label_colors": {"SUM(sum_boys)": "#ff0000", "SUM(sum_girls)": "#00ff00"}
```

where the keys are my label name

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. You have to  provide the label in small. it should be like:

```
"label_colors": {"sum(sum_boys)": "#ff0000", "sum(sum_girls)": "#00ff00"}
```